# SQL Server: Delete multiple rows based on result output

Tags: sql, database, delete-row

In SQL Server I have a table named: `CustomerAddr` and a row named: `Stnumber` . I have non-integer values that I want to delete. I would like to delete the rows of the non-integer values.  I use this query that shows the results of the non-integer values:

```
Select * From [CustomerAddr] [Stnumber] Where ISNUMERIC ([Stnumber]) = 0
```

The results show 400 rows, not in sequential order. How do I delete based on results, any help would be great.

I use this query:

Delete FROM CustomerAddr WHERE ISNUMERIC StNumber = '0';

when I use the delete and ISNUMERIC before STnumber I get a message: "An expression of Non-Boolean type specified in context where a condition is expected near 'Stnumber'

Comment: better to read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx

Comment: Just replace `Select *` with `DELETE`.

Comment: FYI `ISNUMERIC` returns true if the value can be converted to a numeric data type. This includes real, float, money. For that reason non-number characters like `'+', '-', 'd', 'e', '$','£'` are allowed. So just be careful while using `Isnumeric`

Answer (score 2):

Just use the DELETE instead of the SELECT

```
DELETE From [CustomerAddr] Where ISNUMERIC ([Stnumber]) = 0
```

Comment: I get a message; "Incorrect Syntax  near 'Stnumber'

Answer (score 1):

you can use `where` in `delete` statements:

```
delete From [CustomerAddr] Where ISNUMERIC ([Stnumber]) = 0
```

Comment: when I use the delete and ISNUMERIC before STnumber I get a message: "An expression of Non-Boolean type specified in context where a condition is expected near 'Stnumber'